# Stokes's first Problem/Rayleigh plate $u(0,t)=t^n$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

So basically we have Stoke's first Problem/Rayleigh plate, meaning an impulsively starting Plate with the boundary conditions $u(0,t)=t^n$ and $u(\infty,t)=0$. In theory it is easy to solve the PDE, if $u(0,t)$ wouldn't be time-dependent! Do you have an idea how to solve it with the similarity Ansatz, taking an Ansatz like $\eta=y/g(t)$ and $u^*(\eta)=u(x,t)/A(t)$?

[image: Problemdescription]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'in theory it is easy to solve the PDE'. How would you solve it? The time dependence in the initial condition doesn't really make much of a difference. And what have you tried in order to get the similarity solution? If you google 'similarity solution heat equation' you will get numerous pages that explicitly describe how to derive and solve the problem at hand.

Comment: @Mattos I just took the Stoke's first problem similarity solutions as a blueprint. Basically eta is something like eta=y/2sqrt(vt) right? And I would assume A(t) to be Ut^n? I have problems how to choose my A(t) and eta basically. And I could not end up with the erfc anymore. We just had that example during the lecture. How would you solve it? The Heat Equation was derived to fullfill it's BC and assumptions where made that could not be fullfilled in this case, right?